# Executing reactive expressions one after another - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a reactive value (some chosen piece of text) and two pieces of reactive code that need to run sequentially: the first shows the text to the user via renderUI(), and the second calls some javascript functions to make modification to the displayed HTML.

I tried having a separate trigger event for the second reactive code, and to have the first reactive code trigger it, as suggested in this answer:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-set-up-triggers-or-execution-order-for-eventreactive-or-observeevent/7720

Like this:

```
rv <- reactiveValues()
rv$run2 <- 0

observeEvent(whateverTrigger, { 
   whateverCode
   rv$run2 <- rv$run2 + 1
})

observeEvent(rv$run2, {
   whateverCode
})
```

But it seems that this causes the first reactive to be evaluated again and again because it also depends on the rv$run2 reactive.

**EDIT**

Here is a minimal reprex for the one renderUI and one observeEvent both reacting to the same value. What I want is for the observeEvent to run after the renderUI has finished. What happens though is that it is executed beforehand.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.alertnum = function(data) {
alert(data);
}'

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("alertnum")),
                numericInput("num", "Number", 0),
              uiOutput("text"))

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output$text<- renderUI({
    wellPanel(input$num)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$num, {
    js$alertnum(input$num)
  })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list("host" = "0.0.0.0", "port" = 7000))
```

If I use the suggestion quoted and change the observeEvent to react to a different trigger, triggered by the renderUI, this doesn't work as the renderUI is evaluated again and again:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.alertnum = function(data) {
alert(data);
}'

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("alertnum")),
                numericInput("num", "Number", 0),
              uiOutput("text"))

server <- function(input, output){
  
  trigger <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  output$text<- renderUI({
    trigger(trigger() + 1)
    print("TEST")
    wellPanel(input$num)
  })
  
  observeEvent(trigger, {
    js$alertnum(input$num)
  })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list("host" = "0.0.0.0", "port" = 7000))
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a small but reproducible example to understand the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @RonakShah added now, thank you

Comment: This line gives an error `extendShinyjs(text = jsCode)`. It returns `Error: shinyjs: extendShinyjs: \`functions\` argument must be provided.`

Comment: @RonakShah it works for me but I think it depends on the availability of the V8 package. I added the functions argument so that the code should run regardless of that

Comment: The issue is `renderUI` only executes when you finish typing in `numericInput` i.e when you focus out from the input. On the other  hand `observeEvent` executes as soon as there is a change in the number. You'll see one of the drawback of this when you type in 2 or 3 digit number in the input box. You might need to use some javascript to work around this issue or why not add a button click for user to click on and show the alert message on that button click instead?